# TSLint: no-backbone-get-set-outside-model error thrown for JavaScript map.set() function

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

I am fixing lint errors using Microsoft's  `tslint-microsoft-contrib`. It throws the following error which I think a false alarm.

`Backbone set() called outside of owning model`

```
var mapSet = new Map();
mapSet.set('base', {     
            id: 'base',
            label: 'label',
            type: 'type'
        }); // Error shown here: Backbone set() called outside of owning model: mapSet.set('base'...) (no-backbone-get-set-outside-model)
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Strangely assigning the string `'base'` to a variable made the error disappear.

var base = 'base';
mapSet.set(base, {     
            id: 'base',
            label: 'label',
            type: 'type'
        }); 

NOTE: This lint error is only related to Backbone.js. You can disable this error if you don't use Backbone.js

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib/issues/708#issuecomment-450494396) issue comment from [`tslint-microsoft-contrib`](https://github.com/microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib) the rule you are mentioning is a rule that is specific to [Backbone.js](https://backbonejs.org/) and since your case doesn't have anything to do with Backbone, you can just disable it in your `tslint.json`.

Comment: You can also ignore the rule for this line: 
`// tslint:disable-next-line:no-backbone-get-set-outside-model`
Some environments (PowerBI) asks that you submit code with no changes to tslint.json.